# Linearization of Implicit ODE (Equations of Motion)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

let's say we have a system with vector $q_{(t)}$ representing the degrees of freedom (DoF), and state vector $ x_{(t)} = \left \{ \begin{array}{c c} q_{(t)} \\ \dot{q_{(t)}} \end{array} \right \}$ which includes each DoF and it's corresponding velocity. The system dynamics are often represented implicitly as follows (I'll omit the dependence on time of the state variables from now on) :

$$
M_{(q)} \dot{x} = H_{(q,\dot{q})} = H_{(x)}
$$

where $M_{(q)}$ is the 'Mass-matrix'. In the case $M = I$, the identity matrix, the system is *explicit*.
The system can be rendered explicit quite simply as follows:

$$
\dot{x} = M_{(q)}^{-1}H_{(x)} = \hat{H}_{(x)}
$$
To linearise around an equilibrium point $x_0$, we would take the Jacobian of $H_{(x)}$, and the system dynamics would be, in the explicit case, approximated as
$$
\dot{x} = J_{(x_0)}  (x-x_0) \\
J_{(x_0)} = \nabla_xH_{(x)}|_{(x=x_0)}
$$

My question is, how to deal with linearisation in the *implicit* case? 
Are the following cases equivalent?

$$
\dot{x} = M_{(q)}^{-1}J_{(x)} = M_{(q)}^{-1}\nabla_xH_{(x)} \stackrel{?}{=} \nabla_x\hat{H}_{(x)} =\nabla_x[M_{(q)}^{-1}H_{(x)}]
$$

In other words, is it imperative to render the EoM explicit first?
 In even simple systems where a viewer can quite easily imagine the dynamics when looking at the implicit form, the explicit form becomes extremely long, unintuitive, not to mention very difficult to compute.
Are there any workarounds that avoid solving $[M_{(q)}^{-1}H_{(x)}]$?

Comment: I guess you could invert $J$ instead?

Comment: We have $M\dot x = J(x-x_0)$ after linearisation. Instead of inverting $M$ to get $\dot x = (M^{-1} J(x-x_0))$ maybe in some cases it is easier to invert $J$ to get $x = x_0 + J^{-1}M\dot x$? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: I've edited the question to try and make it clearer. My question is whether $M^{-1}J$ is equivalent to taking the Jacobian of $[M^{-1}H]$ (the dynamics rendered explicit). Intuitively it seems to be, but I have trouble seeing how to prove it, since $M$ is also non-linear and would affect the dynamics...

Comment: I think that's valid if and only if $M$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: That's what I figured....hence the question of how to avoid making it explicit. Note that $M$ is dependent (non-linearly) on $q$ but independent of $\dot{q}$.